# Compiling simple code in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I am trying to compile simple programs in Terminal, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
printf("Enter length of square:");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Perimeter of your square is:%d\n", 4*a);
return 0;
}
```

Save it in file begin1.txt in home directory, then type in Terminal cc begin1.txt it says like:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file begin1.txt, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6F 0x2E ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): begin1.txt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you use `.cpp` instead of `.txt` the compiler will know what kind of file it is?

Answer (score 0):

> *ld: warning: ignoring file begin1.txt*, ***file was built for unsupported file format*** *( 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6F 0x2E )* *which is not the architecture* *being linked* *(x86_64):* *begin1.txt*

The error statement issued by your compiler specifies that your file saved with a `.txt` File extension, which makes it a text file, not a C++ file. You need to change your filename to end with a `.cpp` file extension:

```
 begin1.cpp
```